# PAM: Permission denied with pam_google_authenticator

Tags: ssh, pam, sshd

I've an Amazon Linux 2 (centos-based) VM. I've created a new local user called `bastion` to use it with SSH. Now I want to add `pam_google_authenticator` as the second factor auth method.

I've modified `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` accordingly. When trying to login with SSH I see on the client side:

> Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).

And on the server side (`journalctl -u sshd`) I see:

> sshd[4275]: error: PAM: Permission denied for bastion from [DNS name]

What should I do to grant to `bastion` user required permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as I've already figured it out.

This error:

> sshd[4275]: error: PAM: Permission denied for bastion from [DNS name]

is not necessarily related to the UNIX permissions (although can be).

In my case it was missing `google-authenticator` configuration for my `bastion` user. Remember that the default location of `.google_authenticator` configuration file is `~/.google_authenticator`.

Comment: I'm currently hunting a similar issue, but I've set `nullok` on `pam_google_authenticator.so` so it should not cause a permission denied error. So while in theory the `nullok` should permit an user to bypass google authenticator if that flie is missing for them, it does not. Tested with the debian package verion `20191231-2`